# Disabling Geode Pulse in Apache Geode

Tags: apache-commons, geode, pulse, apache-commons-text

I have apache-geode-1.15.1 installed on multiple Linux servers. Is there a way to disable Geode Pulse (located in <GEODE_HOME>/tools/Pulse/geode-pulse-1.15.1.war) in Apache Geode? I'm encountering a security vulnerability and Geode Pulse is a major suspect.

I tried to edit the configuration `http-service-port=0` in the file config/gemfire.properties in order to fix the Apache Commons Text4Shell security vulnerability, but it produces the vulnerable commons-text-1.9.jar file. I'm expecting that Geode will not create the jar file if I disable Geode Pulse.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!